# Creating file from CD-based application on user computer

Tags: windows, privileges

My app, which is run on arbitrary computer on Widows XP/Vista/7 on arbitrary account (f.e. user with limited privileges) needs to open a file that is wrapped within another file. It can open this embedded file only by file name so the app needs to unwrap the file, store it as another file and then open it.

What can I do to be sure that I have enough privileges to create a file and read/write it?
Is there any special place I can store my files in such situation in Windows. 
Can I use memory mapped files? - can they be read by standard IO operations like OpenFile/ReadFile ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain, what do you mean by "wrapped file" exactly?

Comment: The file is the DICOM Encapsulated PDF. This file has some important data stored in "tags" and one of this "tags" holds PDF file. I open the file using Adobe Reader ActiveX, I need to pass the name of the PDF file to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user should also be able to write in the %USERPROFILE% dir. That one should always exist by design.

But this is obviously different directory for each user.

**edit:**
Windows API includes [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(v=VS.85).aspx) function. It looks in these variables %TMP%, %TEMP%, %USERPROFILE%
If it can not find anything there it returns the windows directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be able to create files in `%TEMP%`.

Comment: Does the temporary folder always exists?

Comment: It could not exist, but in this case other software which is using Windows API to create temporary files would also have problems.